# A non-null-homotopic map from $T^{3}$ into $S^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we collapse the 2-skeleton of $T^{3}$ and we denote this map by $q$,
\begin{equation}
q:T^{3}\rightarrow S^{3}
\end{equation}
Then compositing $q$ with Hopf fibration,
\begin{equation}
S^{1}\hookrightarrow S^{3}\rightarrow S^{2}
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
f:T^{3}\rightarrow S^{2}
\end{equation}

$f$ induces trivial map between homotopy groups and reduced homology groups. But I can not find other invariants to show $f$ is not null-homotopic and do not understand how to solve it.

I will appreciate your help for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**Big Hint:** Use the fact that the Hopf fibration is a fibration (i.e the homotopy lifting property).